# Google Drive SDK file download with Progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am trying to download file from Google Drive

```
[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *fetchError) 
{
    if (fetchError == nil) {
        // Download succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Download succeeded.");
        [self.delegate delegateDownloadedFileWithFileDetails:file downloadedData:data];
    }

    else
         NSLog(@"%@", fetchError.description);
}];
```

Download is working fine .

Now I want to set a progressbar depends on download .Which method should I called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
[fetcher setReceivedProgressBlock:^(int64_t bytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesWritten) {

    NSLog(@"%lld %lld", bytesWritten ,totalBytesWritten);

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.fetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
[self.fetcher setReceivedDataBlock:^(NSData *data) {
    float percentTransfered = self.fetcher.downloadedLength * 100.0f / self.fetcher.response.expectedContentLength;
    // Do something with progress
}
```

Comment: which header file should import for "GTMHTTPFetcher" ? @Anup G Prasad

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: #import "GTMHTTPFetcher.h"
@rollstuhlfahrer https://github.com/google/gtm-http-fetcher/wiki explains about gtm-http-fetcher